# Can't fix ProductsController PUT update errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a problem with workshop app that i'm doing right now. I can't fix two last errors from tests. In my opinion application is working fine in browser. Maybe there is something wrong with tests? Any help would be appreciated.

Two errors:

```
1) ProductsController PUT update with valid params updates the requested product
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: update

2) ProductsController PUT update with invalid params re-renders the 'edit' template
 Failure/Error: response.should render_template("edit")
   expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <[]>
```

Test code:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe ProductsController do
  let(:category) { create(:category) }
  let(:valid_attributes) { { "title" => "MyString", "category_id" => category.id, "price" => 5.59,                
  "description" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"} }
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "PUT update" do
    let(:user) { build(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      controller.stub(:user_signed_in?).and_return(true)
      controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)
      controller.stub(:authenticate_user!).and_return(user)
    end

    describe "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested product" do
        product = Product.create! valid_attributes
        Product.any_instance.should_receive(:update).with({ "title" => "MyString" })
        put :update, { id: product.to_param, product: { "title" => "MyString" }, category_id:                    
        category.to_param }, valid_session
      end
    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "re-renders the 'edit' template" do
        product = Product.create! valid_attributes
        Product.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
        put :update, { id: product.to_param, product: { "title" => "invalid value" }, category_id:             
        category.to_param }, valid_session
        response.should render_template("edit")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

ProductsController#update code:

```
def update
  if self.product.update(product_params)
    redirect_to category_product_url(category, product), notice: 'Product was successfully  
    updated.'
  else
    render action: 'edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**In general**

```
expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <[]>
```

Typically this means that you are expecting a render (following a validation failure for example) and your controller perform a redirect (after a successful saving of your model)

---

**In you code**

You stub the `save` method here:

```
Product.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
```

But call an action that uses the `update` method

```
if self.product.update(product_params)
```

So the action succeed -> your controller redirects -> your 'edit' template is not rendered -> your spec fails

**Your solution**

Instead of stubbing `save`, you should stub `valid?`, it's the good practice in that case

```
Product.any_instance.stub(:valid?).and_return(false)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Benjamin, but sadly it didn't resolve my problems. I'm getting the same errors as before.

Comment: You still receive the error #2? `expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <[]>`, you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed.

Comment: So there is something you are not telling us, because the code you posted with the modifications I advise to you would work.